# Matlab: Concatenating information from multiple sheets

Tags: matlab

I have an excel file 'Bool1.xlsx' with sheets named: 'Sheets1', 'Sheets2'.

Sheet1 has information of following sort:

```
Month         Val1   Val2    
1-Feb-14     (1.17)  (13.18)     
1-Apr-14     (1.12)  (195.39)    
Total        (3.08)  (180,501.38)
```

Sheet2 has infomation of sort:

```
Month         Val1   Val2    
1-Feb-14     (3.17)  (17.18)     
1-Apr-14     (2.12)  (15.39)     
Total        (3)     (10,51.38)
```

I want to create a Sheet 3 which pulls information from Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 and adds a column at the end like:

```
Month         Val1   Val2        Source
1-Feb-14     (1.17)  (013.18)    Sheet1
1-Apr-14     (1.12)  (195.39)    Sheet1
1-Feb-14     (3.17)  (17.18)     Sheet2
1-Apr-14     (2.12)  (15.39)     Sheet2
```

If the sheets only that numerical values I don't find it hard to do it elegantly but with mixture of numerical and text values I am not able to do it in a clean manner. Any ideas guys ?

Edit:

I must achieve this in Matlab as this is part of another bigger piece of Matlab code that I am running.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mind just doing it straight in Excel? Or do you have to use Matlab?

Comment: Yes I need to do this in Matlab as this will part of bigger piece of Matlab code that I am working with.

Comment: The easy way would be to add the sheet name before combining the two sheets. Just as @Dan demonstrates in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `xlsread`?

So something like:

```
[~,~,Sheet1] = xlsread(myXLSfile, 'Sheet1');
[~,~,Sheet2] = xlsread(myXLSfile, 'Sheet2');

Sheet1(:, end+1) = {'Sheet1'};
Sheet2(:, end+1) = {'Sheet2'};

[Sheet1; Sheet2]
```

Comment: I suppose it could be reduced slightly by using `Sheet1(:,end+1)={'Sheet1'}`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Ya that's much better